# iTunes connect update limited to some countries?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, release

I have an app available for multiple countries; and now I need to release an update only to some of this countries.

Example
An app available for the whole world, is going to get an update, but it should only be available for USA users for instance.

Is it possible to release this update only to the USA store, or somehow limit it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible and there's no sensible reason to do this.

Comment: @skorulis so far the reason is that we are unable to turn on/off a feature on our backend side. But yeah, there are reasons you might want to release incrementally. We aim at something like what Google does releasing to a subset of users.

Answer (score 3):

If you limit the app to any geographical extent, then current users will be able to use it, but it won't appear to anyone on iTunes.

So, if you wanted an update for some region while having the previous version available, the answer is **no**, there's no way to do that.

@skorulis I find many reasons why you could want to do so, e.g. incremental release of the app update amongst many others.

Comment: You recall any formal definition by Apple about this? I'd like to give a reason other than "no, we can't" but I can't find anything on the docs

Comment: Sure. I would just go to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html and see the process. It is quite straightforward: prepare new version; submit for review; replace old version. In the docs, there is no possible way to do otherwise.

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with the process. I was just wondering if the docs stated that it is in fact impossible to release country-specific updates. In any case, thanks for the input and the data!

Comment: No. It's not stated otherwise. However, the process shows there's no other way to publish a version than with a single binary.